# Stsadm - Avoid subsites while exporting a site

Tags: stsadm, export, sharepoint-enterprise

I am exporting a site using `stsadm` command. It is automatically exporting the subsites too. I need to take the current site only, how can I restrict the subsites being exported?

For example I'm exporting the site, http://site1/subsite1

The subsite1 has 4 child sites. I need to avoid that 4 child sites from that export list.

The command I am using is

> stsadm -o export -url http://site1/subsite1 -filename c:\backup.cmp

Answer (score 1):

In scenarios like this, I will export the desired site and it's subsites and import it to a dummy site collection.  After it's imported, I delete away the unwanted subsites, export it again, and import it to the final location.

Comment: do you think it is right way. But no problem, i am asking whether it is the functionality of stsadm command. Or there is option for that.

Comment: I don't think there is an option to exclude subsites.

Comment: There isn't an option to limit the export to one particular subsite only.  It will grab the entire tree of sites from that level down.

Answer (score 0):

stsadm cannot do what you are asking unfortunately, however you can achieve the same functionality using SharePoint Designer, which will create a .cmp (which is a cab file by another name) file which you can import using either stsadm or SharePoint Designer as you prefer.

Here are some links to SharePoint Designer as well:

- [SharePoint Designer 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=21581) (works with WSS3 and SharePoint 2007)
- [SharePoint Designer 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=16573) (works with SharePoint 2010, 2007 and
  WSS3(last 2 with reduced functionality))
- [SharePoint Designer 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/download/details.aspx?id=35491) (works with SharePoint 2013)

A quick example on how to use SharePoint Designer 2007, to illustrate:
Initially go to `File > Open Site` and you will be presented with a request for either a local directory containing a site or a URL, enter the URL of your SharePoint site.

Once you have done you may have to authenticate, just follow the on-screen prompts, and fill in the details for your admin level account.

Now you can see the `Folder List` (far left) and `Web Site` (main part) windows are populated.

Select a site from the Folder List (single left click) then navigate to `Site > Administration > Backup Website` whereupon you will be presented with a requester again which has a check-box to include sub-sites.

Leave this un-ticked and Voila! you can export a site without its children.

Nice and straight-forward.

Comment: I think more details about how you can create the .cmp with designer would be very helpful :)

Comment: Ahh sorry:) will add that now:)

Comment: Great! Now it looks awesome!

Comment: Cheers by the way, I tend to forget to explain when I am in a hurry, so thanks for the reminder:)

Answer (score -1):

For Import and Export of a web, list, or library you can use [Export-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx) and [Import-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx)

To export use:

```
Export-SPWeb http://site –Path "site export.cmp"
```

Then try to import

```
Import-SPWeb http://site –Path export.cmp –UpdateVersions -Overwrite
```